# Passing Array to Another Form (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I got a form which declared an array in public,

```
Public requestedqueue() As Integer
```

I would like to pass the array to form3 and perform other calculations there, but how?
I tried doing(at a new form):

```
public newrequest() As Integer
newrequest = form2.requestedqueue
```

I tried to show it at a new form by doing:

```
TextBox1.Text = = String.Join(",",form2.newrequest)
```

But whenever I run into form3 it would say the newrequest is null.
But it shows as an array in form2, Im so confused.

Comment: This is not enough information for us to reproduce a problem. Do you actually ever populate the array? How do you open `Form2` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> But it shows as an array in form2

but `newrequest` will be `Nothing` because you have set it equal to the value of `requestedqueue` which is `Nothing` until you populate the array with some values.

If you had `Public requestedqueue() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}` then you would not encounter the error.

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass data to a form is to add a property to the second form.

Lets say you have a form called `Form3` and this is your form's code. In the code you will need to declare an array of integer to hold the passed data, and also declare a public property so you have a way of passing the array

```
Public Class Form3
    Dim requestedqueue() As Integer

    Public Property ArrayParameter As Integer()
        Get
            Return arrayData
        End Get
        Set(value() As Integer)
            arrayData = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Then, to pass the data from `Form1`, in form1, you would simply use

```
Form3.ArrayParameter=requestedqueue()
```

to set the parameter.

and if you wish, you can show the form as normal, or if the form is already visible, you can process the code using button clicks etc.

If you want to process the data in an already open form immediately without any user interaction, you can write a Procedure that does the processing and include that in the `Set` portion of your property.

For example. If you want to add all the elements of the array to a `ListBox` called `ListBox1` in `Form3`, you could write a procedure like this..

```
Private Sub AddDataToListbox()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item As Integer In requestedqueue
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

and  change your `Form3.ArrayParameter` code to this

```
Public Property ArrayParameter As Integer()
    Get
        Return requestedqueue
    End Get
    Set(value() As Integer)
        requestedqueue = value
        AddDataToListbox()
    End Set
End Property
```